# Disable Postsharp in debug builds for entire solution

Tags: postsharp

I have a solution with many projects and I would like to disable Postsharp for debug builds to reduce local developer build times. Is there any way to do this without editing each project file?

I know this may sound like a bad idea, but we are only using Postsharp for exception logging and our builds go through several environments for automated/manual testing (which would use a release build), so we would pick up on any potential issues at this point.

If it helps, Postsharp was added to the projects via nuget.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the compilation symbol (constant) "SkipPostSharp" for Debug mode only.

Comment: Thanks Gael. Is there a way to do this for the entire solution without editing each project's settings?

Comment: Yes, you can use a file named PostSharp.Custom.targets as documented in http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Content.aspx/PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/b1071f40-36ec-488c-a418-c9f19e3c8dbc.htm

Comment: See also the following related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814609/is-it-possible-to-select-which-projects-postsharp-processes-instead-of-telling-i/9826387#comment12630139_9826387

Comment: For Visual Studio for Mac Community edition v8.10, this can be done under Project -> <Project Name> Options -> Compiler -> Define Symbols -> add SkipPostSharp into the ';' separated list

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do it for the entire solution, but it can be done easily
per project.

1. **Project > Setting > PostSharp**
2. Choose *Yes* for **Disable PostSharp for this configuration**

[image: Disable PostSharp]

Comment: This doesn't work if one hasn't got PostSharp installed.